# Failed- Path too long error while downloading file in Chrome using selenium

Tags: selenium, chromium

I want to download file in my current working directory using selenium automation. But I am getting 'Path too long' error. The code I have written so far is:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
current_directory = os.getcwd()
windows_cwd = current_directory.replace('\\','\\\\')+'\\\\'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': windows_cwd,
         'download.directory_upgrade': True,
         'safebrowsing.enabled': False,
         'safebrowsing.disable_download_protection': True
         }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

My current working directory is:

> C:\Users\US177\PycharmProjects\Plugin

where the path is too long.

But it successfully downloads to

> C:\Users\US177\Desktop

[failed-long path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lrYx.png)

Comment: Because it is set by chrome settings. You cant set it with chromedriver.

Comment: Error stack trace please

Comment: @DebanjanB No error is displayed on console. I have attached the screenshot of the error that appears on web page.

Comment: What's the full name of the file you are downloading? My guess is that it's really long and it's just enough to push it over the edge when downloading to your working dir but not the Desktop.

Comment: @sunil shrestha Were you able to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

While setting your download path, try using double backslash (ie. path\\to\\directory).

See this [Github issue about programatically downloading from chrome](https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/87)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is based on the information provided, but I'm guessing it's along the lines of "Why is this happening?", so I will address that question.

The maximum length of a file name in Windows is 260 characters. The file is able to download to your desktop because the name of the file (when appended to your path) does not exceed this limit. When trying to download to PycharmProjects\Plugin\ folder, the path has become too long.

Comment: But its not too long that exceeds 260 characters.

Comment: @sunilshrestha Are you able to share the CSV file name that you are attempting to download? I don't see why else you would receive a "Failed - Path too long" error message unless the path was too long.

Comment: The csv file name is: "W3Schools Online Web Tutorials.CSV"